# Optional month or day in MySQL date field from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a problem where I need to handle dates where the month and day parts are optional. For example, the year will always be known but sometimes the day or month and day will be unknown.

In MySQL I can create a table with a date field and while I can't find any reference in the MySQL Manual it will accept the following as valid:

```
(YYYY-MM-DD format):
2011-02-10    // Current date
2011-02-00    // Day unknown so replaced with 00
2011-00-00    // Day and month unkown so replaced with 00-00
```

Test calculations from within the database work fine so I can still sort results easily. In the manual it says that month needs to be between 01 and 12, and day between 01 and 31 - but it does accept 00.

First question: Am I going to run into trouble using 00 in the month or day parts or is this perfectly acceptable?

Next question: Is there a PHP function (or MySQL format command) that will automatically format the following dates into the required format string?

```
2011      becomes   2011-00-00
2011-02   becomes   2011-02-00
```

Or do I need write a special function to handle this?

The following doesn't work:

```
<?php
$date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', '2011-00-00');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
// Returns 2010-11-30

$date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', '2011-02-00');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
// Returns 2011-01-31 
?>
```

Third question: Is there a PHP function (or MySQL command) to format the dates for use in PHP?

Finally, is this the best approach? Or is there a 'best practise' method?

---

EDIT:

Here is what I'm currently doing:

A date field can accept a date in the format YYYY, YYYY-MM, or YYYY-MM-DD and before sending to the database it is processed in this function:

```
/**
* Takes a date string in the form:
*   YYYY or
*   YYYY-MM or
*   YYYY-MM-DD
* and validates it
* 
* Use date_format($date, $format); to reverse.
* 
* @param string $phpDate Date format [YYYY | YYYY-MM | YYYY-MM-DD]
* 
* @return array 'date' as YYYY-MM-DD, 'format' as ['Y' | 'Y-m' | 'Y-m-d'] or returns false if invalid
*/
function date_php2mysql($phpDate) {
    $dateArr = false;
    // Pattern match
    if (preg_match('%^(?P<year>\d{4})[- _/.]?(?P<month>\d{0,2})[- _/.]?(?P<day>\d{0,2})%im', trim($phpDate), $parts)) {
        if (empty($parts['month'])) {
            // Only year valid
            $date = $parts['year']."-01-01";
            $format = "Y";
        } elseif (empty($parts['day'])) {
            // Year and month valid
            $date = $parts['year']."-".$parts['month']."-01";
            $format = "Y-m";
        } else {
            // Year month and day valid
            $date = $parts['year']."-".$parts['month']."-".$parts['day'];
            $format = "Y-m-d";
        }
        // Double check that it is a valid date
        if (strtotime($date)) {
            // Valid date and format
            $dateArr = array('date' => $date, 'format' => $format);
        }
    } else {
        // Didn't match
        // Maybe it is still a valid date
        if (($timestamp = strtotime($phpDate)) !== false) {
            $dateArr = array('date' => date('Y-m-d', $timestamp), 'format' => "Y-m-d");
        }
    }
    // Return result
    return $dateArr;
}
```

So it pattern matches the input $phpDate where it must begin with 4 digits, then optionally pairs of digits for the month and the day. These are stored in an array called $parts.

It then checks if months or days exist, specifying the format string and creating the date.

Finally, if everything checks out, it returns a valid date as well as a format string. Otherwise it returns FALSE.

I end up with a valid date format for my database and I have a way of using it again when it comes back out.

Anyone think of a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you expect as result in your samples?

Comment: The MySQL samples work if in the format YYYY-MM-DD no matter if they have 00 or not. The PHP examples return the result in the comment but I was wanting it to format 2011-00-00 in the first and 2011-02-00 in the second.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a problem where I need to handle dates where the month and day parts are optional. 
>   For example, the year will always be known but sometimes the day or month and day will be 
>   unknown.

In many occasions, we do need such 'more or less precise' dates, and I use such dates as `2011-04-01` (precise), as well as `2011-04` (= April 2011) and `2011` (year-only date) in archives metadata. As you mention it, MySQL date field tolerates '2011-00-00' though no FAQs tell about it, and it's fine.
   But then, I had to interface the `MySQL database` via `ODBC` and the date fields
are correctly translated, except the 'tolerated' dates (Ex: '2011-04-00' results empty in the resulting MySQL-ODBC-connected ACCESS database.
  For that reason, I came to the conclusion that the MySQL date field could be converted in a plain `VARCHAR(10)` field : As long as we don't need specific MySQL date functions, it works fine, and of course, we can still use php date functions and your fine date_php2mysql() function.

I would say that the only case when a MySQL date field is needed
is when one needs complex SQL queries, using `MySQL` date functions in the query itself.
(But such queries would not work anymore on 'more or less precise' dates!...)

**Conclusion** : For 'more or less precise' dates, 
I presently discard MySQL date field and use plain `VARCHAR(10)` field 
with `aaaa-mm-jj` formated data. Simple is beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data parts are all optional, would it be tedious to store the month, day, and year portions in separate integer fields?  Or in a VARCHAR field?  2011-02-00 is not a valid date, and I wouldnt't think mysql or PHP would be excited about it.  Test it out with str_to_time and see what kind of results you get, also, did you verify that the sorting worked right in MySQL?  If the docs say that 1 through 31 is required, and it is taking 00, you might be relying on what is, in essence, a bug.

Since 2011-02-00 is not a valid date, none of PHP's formatting functions will give you this result.  If it handled it at all, I wouldn't be surprised if you got 2001-01-31 if you tried.  All the more reason to either store it as a string in the database, or put the month, day, and year in separate integer fields.  If you went with the latter route, you could still do sorting on those columns.

Comment: I was concerned that my code could be relying on a bug and that at some point in the future it may be 'fixed'. :)
MySQL does work with the 00 but PHP doesn't.
In the past I've had two fields, one for the date and another for the format. So if I only knew the year I would put 2011-01-01 with a format for 'Y', If I knew the month it would be 2011-02-01 and 'Y-m'. Still allowed me to sort easily via the date field and present the data when returned.

Comment: Fair enough, though I would still think three integer columns would be easier to handle.  It makes for easy presentation in a form, flexible sorting, and you don't have to dance around with formats when you want to display: just jam the fields together and show what's there.

Comment: The trouble with three integer fields is that MySQL doesn't know it is a date so I can't use the date functions for it. If possible I'd still prefer to keep some sort of date format.

Comment: `cast(concat(yearfield, '-', monthfield, '-', dayfield) as date)` and off you go. Probably not particularly efficient, but it'd get the trick done

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem. I ended up using the PEAR Date package. Most date classes won't work with optional months or optional days, but the PEAR Date package does. This also means you don't need custom formatting functions and can use the fancy formatting methods provided by the Date package.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this link in a textbook. This states that month and day values can be zero to allow for the possiblity of storing incomplete or unknown data

http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=s_87mv-Eo4AC&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=mysql+date+of+death+when+month+unknown&source=bl&ots=tcRGz3UDtg&sig=YkwpkAlDtBP1KKTDtqSyZCl63hs&hl=en&ei=Btf5TbL1NIexhAfkveyTAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CFMQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 0):

If you pull your date in pieces from the database you can get it as if it's 3 fields.

```
YEAR(dateField) as Year, MONTH(dateField) as Month, DAY(dateField) as DAY
```

Then pushing those into the corresponding fields in the next bit of PHP will give you the result you're looking for.

```
$day = 0;
$month = 0;
$year = 2013;


echo $datestring;

$format = "Y";
if($month)
{
    $format .= "-m";
    if($day)
        $format .="-d";
    else
        $day = 1;
}
else
{
    $month = 1;
    $day = 1;
}

$datestring = strval($year)."-".strval($month)."-".strval($day);

$date = date($format, strtotime($datestring));
echo $date; // "2013", if $month = 1, "2013-01", if $day and $month = 1, "2013-01-01"
```