# Symfony datetime field with day and month optional

Tags: symfony, datetime

I have a symfony project with a doctrine entity that contains date fields. Everything works fine, but I want to be able to enter the day and month optionally. SO I can enter: 01-01-2014, or just 2014.

The widget exists of the standard 3 select fields. When I only enter the year field, it doesn't validate.

Is there a way to only enter the year ?

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same problem. Within my application I have a date field with year and month, where month was optional. I've decided to do custom mapping type (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types, http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types) and store those values as *varchar* in db. If search possibility is important I think this can be rewritten to store values as *date*, at least in MySQL, since you can store month and day as 00 (compare with https://stackoverflow.com/a/5882493/779084).

Below you can find code for Symfony 2.6.

https://gist.github.com/piotrgradzinski/2a2ba7c1a565dba723f6

Answer (score 1):

In php, a date has a day, month, and year.  You need to have all 3 to have a valid date.  To accomplish your goal, I would suggest creating your own entity that has two fields - a date and a boolean.  When you create a new object, set the date to Jan 1 and the boolean to false.  If the user enters a date, change the boolean to true.  This way even if the user wants to use Jan 1, you will know its a valid date because the boolean was changed.

The user does not need to see the boolean field either, just show them the month and date field and if they input any data, then change the boolean to true when you persist the object.

Comment: :) I was thinking exactly the same thing, but maybe there was a more straightforward solution. Thx

Comment: I was thinking about this more, and instead of a new entity, you could use a datetime instead of date.  You can set the minute to a number initially, and then reset that to a different number if the user adds a date.  You will need your own methods to check for this, but at least its not a new entity.

Comment: Very good idea, will come back to this later if I have implemented it